# How to get code coverage on main function in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, test-coverage

How do I get 100% code coverage on a main function for an application that looks like this?

`lib/main.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Home Page'))),
    );
  }
}
```

`test/main_test.dart`

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:example/main.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Counter increments smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    // Verify that the init page is the Home Page.
    expect(find.text('Home Page'), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

--

### Recreating code coverage:

```sh
$ flutter test --coverage --coverage-path ./coverage/lcov.info
$ genhtml ./coverage/lcov.info -o ./coverage/html
```

**Output**

```
...
Generating output.
Processing file lib/main.dart
Writing directory view page.
Overall coverage rate:
  lines......: 66.7% (4 of 6 lines)
  functions..: no data found
```

and the

`lcov.info`

```
SF:lib/main.dart
DA:3,0
DA:4,0
...
```

---

The only "uncovered" code is:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(App());
}
```

How should I write a test to ensure that this function is covered? Can it be done out-side of an integration test?

Answer (score 1):

`mian` function is an entry point of Flutter application. Usually there are a lot of environment settings and DI instructions for your working app inside `main` (or at least near it) that should be overridden from test.

Unit/widget tests have their own overridden settings, test doubles for tested class and another `main` entry point (as you can see from your own example). Test settings usually take place in `setUp()` function of main.

**Resume:**
It is ok that your tests don't call `main` app function. They have their own `main`. What about 100% code coverage - this purpose not justified. Good coverage percent depends on your testing policy. As for me, I guess 70% is good.

Comment: I agree with you, but there are occasions that you insert initializations inside the `main` function. The value of ensuring that you cover `main` in these cases are important so that you are initializing those dependencies. What would be the approach in a case like that?

Comment: The only solution I see is to move all initialization code you want to test from `main` function to other functions or classes that can be tested. `main` itself cant be tested because it is an entry point without result to return.

Comment: Late to the conversation, but making sure the main method works is what [integration testing](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) is for (although it still doesn't count towards coverage). In an integration test, you will start it by calling the main method.